# brown spots on dracaena

Tags: plant-care, leaves, dracaena

I tried to search about this specific spots, but couldn't find anything relevant.
But I'm also new to plants and gardening, so I probably don't know exactly what I should be looking for.

I got this dracaena lemon lime a few weeks ago, but it started getting a few brown spots on the leaves, as you can see above.
I'm not sure what it is, does anyone know and know how to deal with this?
I usually water once per week since it's been hot, and spray and clean its leaves too.

Thanks!

[image: brown spots on dracaena lemon lime]

[image: brown spots in dracaena lemon lime]

Answer (score 1):

The soil is too wet, and if you're using fertilizers, stop fertilzing completely for at least a year. Make sure the bottom of the pot is not sitting in a humid plate — you can put pebbles under the pot to aerate the bottom. Let the soil dry out completely before watering it again, and then start watering lightly every two weeks. You can test soil dryness with your fingers: you should be able to shift dry soil easily without barely anything sticking to your fingers before watering; the pot will feel light. After a couple of months of watering only when the soil has become quite dry, you should know if the plant is reacting positively to its new watering regime.